# Setting up windows-like "play to TV" on ubuntu

Tags: tv, dlna

I am wondering what is the easiest way to achieve it on ubuntu.

What do I want:
-open player
-choose to play file on TV
-play whole playlist

I have 12.04 ubuntu and samsung UN 40B7000.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is what you want exactly but [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/about/) is a really nice media center.

It has also remote control apps for phones and other operating systems.

Comment: is there a way with mediatomb or rygel, i am a noob so don't be harsh

Comment: I don't know this guys but if they are a kind of DLNA, XMBC support it.